# Execution cancelled on PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql

I made a mistake with an update query on a very large database. I realised my mistake while the update/query was still running and clicked 'cancel query'.

I've checked the History panel (pgAdmin3) and it sais 'Execution Cancelled'. It does not say anything about any rows being affected.

Does this mean that no rows were affected by the update? Is there a way to check a log of some sort to see if any rows were affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres runs a query in a transaction.  The transaction completes as a whole or is cancelled as a whole.  This property is called Atomicity (from [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).)

If your query was cancelled, no rows where affected.